# Correctly store device info with Redux in React Native app

Tags: redux, react-native

I'm currently building a React Native application and wondering if storing device information such:

- if my app has granted location permission
- location service is turned on
- last known user location

in the Redux store can be a good idea.
I have different components that needs to know this informations and storing in Redux can grant me a predictable state.
In the case, maybe I can store them like this:

```
{
  user: {
    id: '123'
    name: 'Markus'
    ...
  },
  device: {
    locationPermission: 'denied'
    locationActive: false
    lastKnownLocation: {
      lat: 44.123,
      lng: 32.123
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Are there any cons about this approach?

Answer (score -1):

Yes off course if you are sharing device info between different screens and component, then storing in store is a good option.